# Differential topology question involving cobordism

Tags: differential-topology, cobordism

Prove that if $X$ and $Z$ are cobordant in $Y$, then for every compact manifold $C$ in $Y$ with dimension complementary to $X$ and $Z$, $I_2(X, C) = I_2(Z, C)$. [HINT: Let $f$ be the restriction to $W$ of the projection map $Y \times I \to Y$ and use the Boundary Theorem.]

Can you talented guys help me with this question?

Comment: What is the definition of $I2(X,C)$? Is it algebraic intersection number?

Comment: And is the $2$ a subscript, a superscript or what?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to make the mathematical expressions easier to read.  Have a look and learn some basic $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @Tom: thanks. But also, please tell us the definition of $I_2$.

Comment: @Grumpy Parsnip it is mod2 intersection number

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Z$ cobound the manifold $W$, consider the intersection of $C$ with $Y$. After perturbing it to be in general position, $C\cap W$ must be a compact $1$-manifold with boundary. The boundary of $C\cap W$ must therefore be an even number of points lying in $X\cup Z$. The points that lie in $X$ are counted mod 2 by $I_2(X,C)$ and the points in $Z$ are counted mod 2 by $I_2(Z,C)$. Thus  $I_2(X,C)+I_2(Z,C)$ is even, which proves the result.

Comment: Thank you so much. That really help me a lot